# Tomcat 9 jenkins build issue

Tags: tomcat9

Step ‘Deploy war/ear to a container’ aborted due to exception:
java.lang.InterruptedException: [DeployPublisher][WARN] No wars found. Deploy aborted. %n
at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:107)
at jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep.perform(SimpleBuildStep.java:123)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:80)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:47)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:818)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:767)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:179)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:711)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1918)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:101)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:442)
Finished: FAILURE

Plz tell me how to get out from this